# PHP add a new key - value pair in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Hi I'd like some help please. I'm having an array like this

```
$my_array = array(
    array(
        'key_1' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'key_2'     => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'key_3'     => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    ),
    array(
        'key_1' => 'Integer lorem quam, adipiscing condimentum tristique vel, eleifend sed turpis.',
        'key_2' => 'Integer lorem quam, adipiscing condimentum tristique vel, eleifend sed turpis.',
        'key_3' => 'Integer lorem quam, adipiscing condimentum tristique vel, eleifend sed turpis.',
    ),
    array(
        'key_1' => 'Pellentesque cursus arcu id magna euismod in elementum purus molestie.',
        'key_2' => 'Pellentesque cursus arcu id magna euismod in elementum purus molestie.',
        'key_3' => 'Pellentesque cursus arcu id magna euismod in elementum purus molestie.',
    ),
);
```

What I'd like to do is to append on each inner array item a `key_4 => value_4`, so in order to do this I used a `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach ($my_array as $item) {
            $item['key_4'] = file_get_contents($some_file);
            // echo '<pre>'. print_r($item) . '</pre>'; // the new keys seems to appended properly here
}
echo '<pre>'. print_r($my_array) . '</pre>'; // the new keys are not in my array (!!!)
```

so what I was hopping to do is this:

```
$my_array = array(
        array(
            'key_1' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
            'key_2'     => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
            'key_3'     => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
            'key_4'     => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        ),
        array(
            'key_1' => 'Integer lorem quam, adipiscing condimentum tristique vel, eleifend sed turpis.',
            'key_2' => 'Integer lorem quam, adipiscing condimentum tristique vel, eleifend sed turpis.',
            'key_3' => 'Integer lorem quam, adipiscing condimentum tristique vel, eleifend sed turpis.',
            'key_4' => 'Integer lorem quam, adipiscing condimentum tristique vel, eleifend sed turpis.',
        ),
        array(
            'key_1' => 'Pellentesque cursus arcu id magna euismod in elementum purus molestie.',
            'key_2' => 'Pellentesque cursus arcu id magna euismod in elementum purus molestie.',
            'key_3' => 'Pellentesque cursus arcu id magna euismod in elementum purus molestie.',
            'key_4' => 'Pellentesque cursus arcu id magna euismod in elementum purus molestie.',
        ),
    );
```

But If I dump my array ( see the print_r out of the loop) I don't get the new key => pair items. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the current `key` of the main array to store new value. Try this -

```
foreach ($my_array as $key => $item) {
    $my_array[$key]['key_4'] = //new value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default foreach create a copy of the array.

To work on the original, iterate by reference:

```
foreach ($my_array as &$item){ //note & char
```

Or use a for loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i++){
    $my_array[$i]['key_4'] = file_get_contents($some_file);
```

Alternativly you can use `array_map`:

```
$my_array = array_map(function($item){
    $item['key_4'] = file_get_contents($some_file);
    return $item;
    }, $my_array);
```

This will overwrite the original array with the modified copy, so is likely to perform worse that the other two options